# PostgreSQL: sum of days in range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as follows:

```
                   Table "public.fish_schedule"
 Column |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 name   | character varying(255) |           | not null | 
 tr     | timerange              |           | not null | 
 mr     | int4range              |           | not null |
```

Example data:

```
     name     |         tr          |   mr   
--------------+---------------------+--------
 ray          | [04:00:00,21:00:00) | [8,12)
 moray eel    | [00:00:00,24:00:00) | [8,11)
 yellow perch | [00:00:00,24:00:00) | [1,4)
(3 rows)
```

The field `mr` represents the month range. I would like to add the total number of days in the range of, for example, moray eel, which would be from August to October.

I've only managed to get the following SQL working so far, and haven't got the faintest idea how to write a function to do what I need.

```sql
SELECT generate_series(1,12) AS n, 
       generate_series('2020-01-01'::date,'2020-12-01'::date,'1 month'::interval)+ '1 month'::interval - generate_series('2020-01-01'::date,'2020-12-01'::date,'1 month'::interval) as m;
```

Here's the output.

```
 n  |    m    
----+---------
  1 | 31 days
  2 | 29 days
  3 | 31 days
  4 | 30 days
  5 | 31 days
  6 | 30 days
  7 | 31 days
  8 | 31 days
  9 | 30 days
 10 | 31 days
 11 | 30 days
 12 | 31 days
(12 rows)
```

So, the function would have to add up the days in August(31), September(30), and October(31), based on the range in the `mr` field.

Would appreciate any guidance or pointers.

UPDATE: Here is the solution for the curious.

```
WITH feeding(name, the_hours, start_schedule, end_schedule) AS
(SELECT name,
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM upper(tr)-lower(tr)),
make_date(extract(year from now())::int4,lower(mr),1)::timestamp,
make_date(extract(year from now())::int4,upper(mr)-1,1)::timestamp
+ interval '1 month' - interval '1 day'
from fish_schedule
)
SELECT name, SUM(the_hours * (EXTRACT (days from (end_schedule - start_schedule)) + 1)) "total_hours"
FROM feeding
GROUP by name
ORDER by total_hours;
```

Comment: If you do this: `select sum(generate_series) from generate_series(1,3);` you will get the sum from 1+2+3. So you will have to do `select generate_series from generate_series(...)` whill allow you to sum the number of days.  [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-srf.html)

Comment: This is a helpful comment, thank you. Yes, I'm trying to perform a `reduce` operation for the elements in the `mr` range, where each element in `mr` represents a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the number of days in a month since your for any given row your time frame in contiguous. The following converts the MT column to timestamps from the 1st day of lower value of range the last date of the upper value of the range in a CTE. The main part the then extracts number of days from the difference.

```
with feeding( name, start_schedule, end_schedule) as 
     ( select name 
            , make_date(extract(year from now())::int4,lower(mr),1)::timestamp
            , make_date(extract(year from now())::int4,upper(mr),1)::timestamp
              + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day'
         from fish_schedule
     )
select name, extract(days from (end_schedule - start_schedule)) + 1 "# of days" 
  from feeding;
```

Note: A slight matter of opinion here. The "interval '1 day' and the addition of 1 in the main can be eliminated and still produce the same result. IMO the above more clearly the intent. But not having them makes the query slightly shorter and 'infinitesimally' faster.

PS. It also handles @Vesa point on leap year.

Comment: I'm on PostgreSQL 12 and the code snippet throws the following error: `ERROR:  date field value out of range: 2020-13-01`

Comment: That is because there is no month 13.  What is the complete error message and the data values.

Comment: That was the complete error message. It seems it doesn't like `UPPER(mr)` since that returns the upper limit of the range, when it is supposed to be a non-inclusive limit. i.e. [1,13) means 1 to 12 inclusive, not 1 to 13. But PostgreSQL stores it as 1 to 13, non-inclusive.

Comment: Looks like an input data error. what do the following produce. select * from fish_schedule where upper(mr)>12;
select distinct upper(mr) from fish_schedule;

Comment: Check how the MR column was created. Perhaps the range was created as:  select int4range(8,12,'[]')  Postgres converts that to int4range(8,13,'[)')

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of days in a year, you could do:

```
select sum(d) from (
   SELECT 
      date_part('month',generate_series) as n,
      generate_series as startOfMonth,
      date_trunc('month',generate_series) + '1 month'::interval - '1 day'::interval  as endOfMonth,
      date_part('days', date_trunc('month',generate_series) + '1 month'::interval - '1 day'::interval) as d
   FROM generate_series('2020-01-01'::date,'2020-12-01'::date,'1 month'::interval)
) x
;
```

This returns 366 days, the inner-query returns:

```
 n  |      startofmonth      |       endofmonth       | d
----+------------------------+------------------------+----
  1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00+01 | 2020-01-31 00:00:00+01 | 31
  2 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00+01 | 2020-02-29 00:00:00+01 | 29
  3 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00+01 | 2020-03-31 00:00:00+02 | 31
  4 | 2020-04-01 00:00:00+02 | 2020-04-30 00:00:00+02 | 30
  5 | 2020-05-01 00:00:00+02 | 2020-05-31 00:00:00+02 | 31
  6 | 2020-06-01 00:00:00+02 | 2020-06-30 00:00:00+02 | 30
  7 | 2020-07-01 00:00:00+02 | 2020-07-31 00:00:00+02 | 31
  8 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00+02 | 2020-08-31 00:00:00+02 | 31
  9 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00+02 | 2020-09-30 00:00:00+02 | 30
 10 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00+02 | 2020-10-31 00:00:00+01 | 31
 11 | 2020-11-01 00:00:00+01 | 2020-11-30 00:00:00+01 | 30
 12 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00+01 | 2020-12-31 00:00:00+01 | 31
(12 rows)
```

I hope this does help to change your query to get the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    name,
    to_date('2020-' || upper(mr) || '-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
    - to_date ('2020-' || lower(mr) || '-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
FROM
    fish_schedule;
```

Do you have to be careful on leap days? 2020 is a leap year.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the leap year issue, thanks for noticing it.